# Is ClientCredentials flow access token only scoped to the specific tenant?

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I wanted to confirm that the access token returned from the /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token endpoint in client credentials flow (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) is only usable to fetch data from the tenant that's specified in the request - i.e. it cannot be used to make an api call against another tenant who's admin has installed the app?

Can you confirm that my understanding is correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on Azure AD, yes. The token you obtained against a specific tenant is only good enough to communicate with endpoints that are configured/permissioned to access by that Tenant.

If you want a multi-tenant approach, you need to follow multi-tenant application flow which specifically mention about `/common`endpoint.

[From documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-send-requests-to-common)

> **Update your code to send requests to /common**
>
> In a single tenant application, sign-in requests are sent to the
> tenant’s sign-in endpoint. For example, for contoso.onmicrosoft.com
> the endpoint would be:
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com. Requests
> sent to a tenant’s endpoint can sign in users (or guests) in that
> tenant to applications in that tenant.
>
> With a multi-tenant application, the application doesn’t know up front
> what tenant the user is from, so you can’t send requests to a tenant’s
> endpoint. Instead, requests are sent to an endpoint that multiplexes
> across all Azure AD tenants: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common